# fileNotFoundException when pointing to ebay.com from mobile

Tags: java, android, url, redirect

If I pass http://www.ebay.com to this. Somewhere along the way ebay changes my url, perhaps a redirect. What's weird is Android java can't open the page.

```
u = new URL(txturl.getText().toString());
```

I get the error below as it apparently opening the new mobile site.  I'm just wonder at what point my url changes and If I somehow stop this. It does not appear to happen if I point to yahoo, google, amazon or other major sites. I just noticed this in my testing.

Thanks.

```
09-07 16:08:08.739: INFO/System.out(360): >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Unable to connect to **http://www.ebay.com - http://m.ebay.com?ebayref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%3A80%2F%3Fredirect%3Dmobile**
09-07 16:08:08.739: WARN/System.err(360): **java.io.FileNotFoundException**: http://m.ebay.com?ebayref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%3A80%2F%3Fredirect%3Dmobile
09-07 16:08:08.749: WARN/System.err(360):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
09-07 16:08:08.759: WARN/System.err(360):     at parser.XXXXXX.com.parserActivity.process(parserActivity.java:106)
09-07 16:08:08.759: WARN/System.err(360):     at parser.XXXXXX.com.parserActivity.access$0(parserActivity.java:68)
09-07 16:08:08.769: WARN/System.err(360):     at parser.XXXXXX.com.parserActivity$1.onClick(parserActivity.java:61)
09-07 16:08:08.779: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-07 16:08:08.779: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-07 16:08:08.789: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-07 16:08:08.789: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 16:08:08.799: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 16:08:08.809: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 16:08:08.809: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 16:08:08.819: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 16:08:08.819: WARN/System.err(360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-07 16:08:08.829: WARN/System.err(360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-07 16:08:08.839: WARN/System.err(360):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @user440279: You may wish to switch to HttpClient, as that is also built into Android, offers a richer API, reportedly performs better, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites force you into broken mobile versions - I keep a second browser on the phone with the user agent string claiming to be a desktop browser instead of a mobile one.  You may need to do this for your app, and make it changeable or do updates as the website changes its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (in my case)

In case when server response code is >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST (greater than 400)
method getInputStream(), of class HttpURLConnectionImpl throws
FileNotFoundException (so you cannot open input stream).

Even if this file exist, your object will not give you input stream, because of server response code is >=400 - **change response code on server** or **use annother class** to connect.

> 09-07 16:08:08.749: WARN/System.err(360):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)

Fragment of source code:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java.html

```
  867       @Override
  868       public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
  869           if (!doInput) {
  870               throw new ProtocolException(Messages.getString("luni.28")); //$NON-NLS-1$
  871           }
  872   
  873           // connect before sending requests
  874           connect();
  875           doRequest();
  876   
  ...
  883           if (responseCode >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
  884               throw new FileNotFoundException(url.toString());
  885           }
  886   
  887           return uis;
  888       }
```